# QGIS Startup.py QMessageBox

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I want to display a message box when I start QGIS that displays the same information each time. What exactly do I write in the start-up.py file ?

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, QCoreApplication, QTimer, Qt
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import QIcon, QColor
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QAction, QMessageBox, QFileDialog
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsVectorLayer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QAbstractItemView
from qgis.utils import iface
import os
import time
import glob

QMessageBox.warning(self.dlg, "Warning", "Please add a report !")
```

I have tried it with several imports, but I always get the error: "self is not defined".

Comment: In Python, "self is not defined" means you cannot use `self` in that context. If you have a look at the [Qt5 docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#warning), you'll see the first parameter of `warning()` is a parent widget. We could perfectly pass a None there and we're done. Just: `from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QMessageBox` and `QMessageBox.warning(None, "Warning", "Please add a report !")`

Comment: Thank you a lot, that perfectly worked !